# How to remove stopwords from an object in Python

Tags: python, nltk

I am working on complaints data which i imported into python from a csv.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(compalints, columns=['issue_detail'])
df.head()
```

I tokenized the data using word tokenizer

```
    issue = df.issue_detail.apply(word_tokenize)
issue.head()
```

The data after tokenizing looks something like this

```
0    [I, have, outdated, information, on, my, credi...
1    [This, company, refuses, to, provide, me, veri...
2    [Need, to, move, into, a, XXXX, facility, ., C...
3    [I, wrote, Equifax, over, 6, weeks, ago, ., Th...
4    [I, received, a, inquiry, alert, from, Experia...
Name: issue_detail, dtype: object
```

now i ma trying to remove the stopwords from this data and using the code

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words=set(stopwords.words("english"))

filtered_sentence = [w for w in issue if not w in stop_words]
```

when i run the filtered sentence part it shows me the error

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I have tried using all the methods listed in the stack overflow, but nothing works as of now

Can anyone please suggest how to remove the stop words from this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `apply` with `list comprehension`:

```
df['issue_detail'] = df.issue_detail.apply(word_tokenize)

f = lambda issue: [w for w in issue if not w in stop_words]
df['issue_detail'] = df.issue_detail.apply(f)
```

Or nested `list comprehension`:

```
df['issue_detail'] = df.issue_detail.apply(word_tokenize)

df['issue_detail'] = [[w for w in issue if not w in stop_words] for issue in df.issue_detail]
```

**Sample**:

```
d = {'issue_detail':[['I', 'have', 'outdated'],
['This', 'company', 'refuses', 'to']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print (df)
                   issue_detail
0           [I, have, outdated]
1  [This, company, refuses, to]

stop_words = set(['I','to'])
f = lambda issue: [w for w in issue if not w in stop_words]
df['issue_detail'] = df.issue_detail.apply(f)
print (df)
               issue_detail
0          [have, outdated]
1  [This, company, refuses]
```

Comment: Hi, tried using it but somehow it has done it in a weird way. it has actually tokenized the words like this                0       [I,  , h, v, e,  , u, e,  , n, f, r, n,  , n, ...
1       [T, h,  , c, p, n,  , r, e, f, u, e,  ,  , p, ...
2       [N, e, e,  ,  , v, e,  , n,  ,  , X, X, X, X, ...

Comment: Do you use `df['issue_detail'] = df.issue_detail.apply(word_tokenize)` in first step? Because it seems in column are not lists.

Comment: @jezrael---- can i use a Name entity recognition in this above example?